# Use regexp_matches in PostgreSQL to validate p o box / p.o. box / P.O. Box / P O Box

Tags: postgresql

Needing help to validate address strings with p.o. box numbers, using regexp_matches (or something else) in PostgreSQL.  They could consist of P.O. Box, P O box, P O BOX, p.o. Box, any combination of mixed, upper, and lower case.

Comment: Is this for a particular nation's postal codes?

Comment: This has worked.  (Finally)

regexp_matches(address, '^((P\.?\s*O\.?)|(POST\s+OFFICE))\s*B\s*O\s*X\s*\d+$','i')

It's not postal code specific.  It's supposed to return variations of P.O. Box due to lack of standardization.

"P.O.BOX 2077"
"PO BOX 5062"
"P.O. BOX 18"
"P. O. BOX 902"
"P O BOX 1078"
"P.O. Box 94"
"P O BOX 358"
"POST OFFICE BOX 5273"